# Problems with Inputs to Char Datatype

Tags: c++, if-statement, inputstream, do-while

Does anyone know why when I input more than one character in the "cInputCommandPrompt" it loops the "Press "Y" to continue, rather just showing it once such as what I'd like it to do. I've tried clearing the buffer? if that's what you call it but it just doesn't seem to work. If anyone could help me I'd greatly appreciate it. I basically want it so when the user doesn't inputs "Y" it just re-loops back to the start until they input the right one. It just doesn't like multiple character inputs which I have tried to sort.

```
void ContinueOptions()
{
    bool bValid = false;
    char cInputCommandPrompt = 0;
    do{
        std::cout << "Press ""y"" to continue: ";
        std::cin >> cInputCommandPrompt;
        cInputCommandPrompt = std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(cInputCommandPrompt));

        if (!std::cin >> cInputCommandPrompt)
        {

            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(100);
            std::cout << "Please try again.";
        }
        else if (cInputCommandPrompt == 'Y')
        {
            bValid = true;
        }
    }while(bValid == false);
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I recommend that you [read a whole line](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) into a string. Then either compare that string directly, or put it into an input string-stream and extract it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an invalid condition in the if statement

```
    if (!std::cin >> cInputCommandPrompt)
```

There should be

```
    if (!( std::cin >> cInputCommandPrompt ) )
```

Rewrite the function at least for example like it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

void ContinueOptions()
{
    bool bValid = false;
    char cInputCommandPrompt = 0;
    do{
        std::cout << "Press ""y"" to continue: ";

        bValid = bool( std::cin >> cInputCommandPrompt );

        if ( bValid )
        {
            cInputCommandPrompt = std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(cInputCommandPrompt));
            bValid = cInputCommandPrompt == 'Y';
        }

        if ( not bValid )
        {

            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(100, '\n');
            std::cout << "Please try again.\n";
        }
    } while( not bValid );
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main(void) 
{
    ContinueOptions();

    std::cout << "Exiting...\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you have written above has created an endless loop for some reason.

Comment: @GeorgeBradley Why is there  an endless loop?

Comment: I don't know why.

Comment: ***I don't know why.*** Perfect time to use a debugger. Any good debugger will allow you to step through code 1 line at a time so you should easily be able to figure out what causes the endless loop.

Comment: @GeorgeBradley See my updated post. There was a typo due to copy and paste your original code.:)

Comment: Thank you very much but sadly my original problem is still there. When I type more than 1 character into the char cInputCommandPrompt it will display the "Press Y to continue more than once when I just want it to display one time. Is there any way I can change this?

Comment: @GeorgeBradley Oh, I have understood. See the anew updated posy.